# Can't figure out why this is not allowed

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Hope you can help understand this, it seemed so natural to do this :

```
    public interface IJob
    {
        bool started { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IJobManager
    {
        void StartJob(IJob job);
    }

    public class SomeJob : IJob
    {
        public bool started { get; set; }
        public void OnlySomeJobDoesThis();
    }

    public class SomeJobManager : IJobManager
    {
        public void startJob(SomeJob job) { } // --> Error'SomeJobManager' does not implement interface member 'IJobManager.StartJob(IJob)' 
    }
```

But it won't compile, as you can see. I can't imagine why, .. as long as SomeJob implements the IJob interface
the compiler should not really have to care ?

Comment: So if I cast `SomeJobManager` to `IJobManager` and pass in my `SomeOtherJob : IJob` to `startJob`, what happens?

Comment: C# is case sensitive. `startJob` is not the same as `StartJob`. If you really need it to be named lowercased, implement the interface explicitly.

Comment: Aside: Naming conventions help avoid casing problems, and help train the eye to spot issues. Here's a great summary of C# naming conventions and recommendations: http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two issues.

First, C# is case sensitive. You define the method as `StartJob` (capital S), but implement `startJob` (lowercase s).

Second, your method takes in SomeJob which implements `IJob`. But your interface says the method should be able to take in an `IJob`. That is, any class which implements the interface, which isn't limited to just `SomeJob`.

Answer (score 5):

Imagine if you've got another class that implements `IJob` :

```
public class FooJob : IJob
{
  // Whatever...
}
```

And you create an instance of your `SomeJobManager` like this:

```
IJobManager manager = new SomeJobManager();
```

Now, when you call `StartJob` like this:

```
manager.StartJob(new FooJob());
```

What would you expect to happen? Your `SomeJobManager` expects a `SomeJob` instance, but the interface says that if must be an `IJob`.

If your code was allowed you'd have broken the contract that the interface promises, which is that `StartJob` can be called with anything that is an `IJob`. You've said in your implementation that it has to be at least a `SomeJob`, which isn't the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your interface is saying "any class that implements me must implement a `StartJob` method that can take **any class that implements IJob**."

Your implementation is saying "My StartJob method only works with **a SomeJob**, I don't know how to handle other implementations of IJob."

Your implementation is more restrictive than the interface, and therefore the compiler doesn't acknowledge that your implementation has fulfilled the interface requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a concrete implementation of `IJob` to the method but it wants an instance of `IJob`.

Just do:

```
 public class SomeJobManager : IJobManager
{
    public void StartJob(IJob job) { } 
}
```

Then just pass in `SomeJob` when you call `StartJob`:

```
//Something like this...
var myJob = new SomeJob();
manager.StartJob(myJob);
```